# How do you do a SELECT nonExistentColumn in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I have a query that does:

```
SELECT "string", Field, Field2, etc.
```

I want to mimic this in Entity Framework so that it can go along with the results of a query:

LINQ...

```
select new 
{
    "STRING", //this is what I want to add to this.                      
    shows.ShowId,
    shows.Title,
    episodes.EpisodeId,
    episodes.EpisodeTitle,
    genres.GenreDescription,
    showTypes.ShowTypeDescription,
    directors.Name,
    episodes.SeasonEpisode
};
```

If I try to add a simple string there, I get:

'Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression'

Comment: Is there any problem with your code?

Comment: yes. 'Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select new 
{
    value = "STRING", //this is what I want to add to this.                      
    shows.ShowId,
    shows.Title,
    episodes.EpisodeId,
    episodes.EpisodeTitle,
    genres = genres.GenreDescription,
    showTypes.ShowTypeDescription,
    directors.Name,
    episodes.SeasonEpisode
};
```

Comment: what if I want the header text of genres.GenreDescription to be "genre" instead of "GenreDescription?"

Comment: just like the first one. `GenreDescription = genres.GenreDescription`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment first. You want `genre` but i thought reverse one. Please try now